# Spring boot for legacy Struts application

Tags: spring-boot, program-entry-point, struts-1

I have come across couple of discussions here about Spring Boot setup for Struts application but did not get a valid yes or no.

I know we can migrate the struts to spring and then use it with Spring boot but considering the timelines and application complexity we need to just migrate from Legacy Websphere to Spring boot for the Struts application.

Can we integrate spring boot with a legacy Struts 1.x application ?

P.S:

So far I am able to start up tomcat for spring boot successfully for my war but I do get 404 on browser so need to understand what would be the flow after the request flow to Main class.

Comment: The short answer no you cannot, simply because Spring dropped Struts 1 support a long time ago. If you don't use Spring with Struts you can use Spring Boot to bootstrap an embedded container but why? You already have a war, just deploy it on a tomcat machine, why would you need Spring Boot for that?

Comment: Hi Deinum, Thank you for your reply. Yes we do have Tomcat configured to deploy the WAR. But before considering that option we wanted to try out spring boot as we have spring boot configured in openshift.

So the answer is, Spring boot cannot be able to help a struts 1.x application to load in its container. ?